# Sorting a JSONArray in java

Tags: android, json, sorting

I'm working on an API where I'm getting a `JSONArray` in which there reside numerous `JSONobjects` containing around 10 `KeyValue` pairs. One of them is `date: 10-3-2015`. I want to use this `JSONArray` in a sorted manner according to the date value. I've tried a various ways including `TreeMap` but no success yet.

A short piece of code or a thorough idea will do the work for me.
Thanks.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: can you post your array?

Answer (score 0):

You can do sorting easily if you use model to hold element in JSONArray.Let's say you have have model Person and JSON array contains list of persons then  you can traverse JSONArray and make list of persons as follows:

```
List<Person> persons=new ArrayList<>();
if(jsonArray!=null){
    for(JSONObject person:jsonArray){
       Person p=new Person();
       //set properties
       //.............
       //add it to persons
       persons.add(p); 
    }
}
```

Now you can sort list of persons as follows:

```
Collections.sort(persons, new Comparator() {
        public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
            if (!(obj1 instanceof Person) || !(obj2 instanceof Person)) {
                return -1;
            }
            Person p1 = (Person)obj1;
            Person p2 = (Person)obj2;
            return p1.getAge() -p2.getAge();
        }
    });
```

Now you can use this sorted list "persons".